# How to set an array of variants from the rowsource range?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba. I have a listbox. It works fine but until recently an error "-2147467259(80004005)
Could not set the rowSource property. Unspecified error" popped out. Usually, I will have to restart the excel for that case.

Edited: Realized when I filter my code multiple time. The error occured.

I have a listbox2 which in UserForm_Initialize(), I populated all the data from listbox1 except that I filter them before I populate the data in.

```
    Dim rData  As Range

    With Sheet1
    Set rData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    rData.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="-"

    'Header
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rSource = .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Use Sheet2 here or a temporary sheet for listbox display purpose only
    Sheet6.Cells.ClearContents
    rSource.Copy Sheet6.Cells(1, 1)

    Set rSource = Sheet6.Range(Sheet6.Cells(1, 1) _
                    , Sheet6.Cells(Sheet6.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
    Set rSource = rSource.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rSource.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                              rSource.Columns.Count)
    End With

    DoEvents '~~> Again this is a must to visually update ListBox display
    ListBox2.RowSource = rSource.Address(external:=True)
    LoadInterface2
```

In sheet 6 (Todiscard cartons) is another temporary sheet for listbox display purpose only

```
 Private Sub LoadInterface2()
    Dim rCombo1 As Range
    Dim rCombo2 As Range
    Dim rCombo3 As Range
    Dim rCombo4 As Range
    Dim rCombo5 As Range
    Dim rCombo6 As Range
    Dim col    As Long
    Dim col2   As Long
    Dim LastRw As Long


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    With Worksheets("ToDiscard Cartons")
        LastRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        'create unique lists for combos using advanced filter
        Range("IM:IV").EntireColumn.ClearContents
        For col = 1 To 6
            col2 = Choose(col, 248, 250, 252, 254, 256, 258)
            .Range(.Cells(1, col), .Cells(LastRw, col)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Cells(1, col2), Unique:=True
        Next col
        Set rSource = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRw, 8))
        Set rCombo1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 248), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 248).End(xlUp))
        Set rCombo2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 250), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 250).End(xlUp))
        Set rCombo3 = .Range(.Cells(2, 252), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 252).End(xlUp))
        Set rCombo4 = .Range(.Cells(2, 254), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 254).End(xlUp))
        Set rCombo5 = .Range(.Cells(2, 256), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 256).End(xlUp))
        Set rCombo6 = .Range(.Cells(2, 258), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 258).End(xlUp))

        With Me
            .ListBox2.RowSource = rSource.Address(external:=True)
            .ComboBox1.RowSource = rCombo1.Address(external:=True)
            .ComboBox2.RowSource = rCombo2.Address(external:=True)
            .ComboBox3.RowSource = rCombo3.Address(external:=True)
            .ComboBox4.RowSource = rCombo4.Address(external:=True)
            .ComboBox5.RowSource = rCombo5.Address(external:=True)
            .ComboBox6.RowSource = rCombo6.Address(external:=True)

        End With

        For Each oCtrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf oCtrl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then oCtrl.ListIndex = -1
        Next oCtrl
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Below is my code when SEARCH button is clicked

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Search button
    Dim rData  As Range

    With Sheet6 'ToDiscard cartons worksheet = sheet6

        Set rData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))

        If Not .AutoFilterMode Then .Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter
        .Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter Field:=lFld, Criteria1:=">=" & sCrit, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & sCrit2

        'Header
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rSource = .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

        On Error GoTo 0
        .Cells(1, 200).CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        rSource.Copy .Cells(1, 200)

        Set rSource = .Cells(2, 200).CurrentRegion
        Set rSource = rSource.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rSource.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                                  rSource.Columns.Count)
    End With

    With Me.ListBox2
        .RowSource = ""
        .RowSource = rSource.Address(external:=True)
    End With

End Sub
```

Below is my code when reset button is clicked

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()  'Reset button
    UserForm_Initialize
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you find out what's causing the error? Using `.List` property is ok but one limitation is not having a header for Listboxes. are you ok with that? For Comboboxes, I guess it's ok. If not, I suggest finding the cause of error and then just handle it.

Comment: .ListBox1.RowSource = rSource.Address(external:=True) is highlighted when I debug. Everything works fine so I have no idea why it popped out that error once in a while. And btw yea, I need header for my listboxes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

To assign array of values to *Listbox and Combobox* you can try this:

```
With Me
    .ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rSource))
    .ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(rCombo1)
    .ComboBox2.List = Application.Transpose(rCombo2)
    .ComboBox3.List = Application.Transpose(rCombo3)
    .ComboBox4.List = Application.Transpose(rCombo4)
    .ComboBox5.List = Application.Transpose(rCombo5)
    .ComboBox6.List = Application.Transpose(rCombo6)
End With
```

Comment: As you mentioned, if I used this. I can't have headers for my listbox. Please advise if this is the only method to solve the error.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I'm still looking at your code to see what might be causing it. But of course you're the one who have the most chance of finding it since you have the data to test with.

Comment: Thank you. The listbox1 is frequently updated with adding, editing and deleting. I'm not sure if these methods overwhelm the listbox1. The error happens out of the blue. If you need the whole file for troubleshooting. Please let me know.

Comment: Yes probably. No need to send the whole file. What you can do is try series of add, delete, edit and I'm sure somewhere, you'll reproduce it. Once you're sure that you can repeat it at will, we can then find the solution. Right now, you're code looks logically ok.

Comment: I found out something. After I filter the listbox1 no. of times, the error occured. I will re-edit my question and please take a look at my code.